# How to copy TextEdit preferences to another computer?

Tags: macos, textedit

Just copying the following file from one computer to another does not transfer my customized preferences for TextEdit

```
~/Library/Containers/com.apple.TextEdit/Data/Library/Preferences/com.apple.TextEdit.plist
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to copy the preference file at `~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.TextEdit.plist`